# Can't reify a suspendable block passed to forEach

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

Given some

```
suspend fun a(): Int
```

This works:

```
launch(Unconfined) {
    (1..10).forEach {
        val a = a()
        println("Result is $a")
    }
}
```

But this fails at compile time:

```
val action: (Int) -> Unit = {
    // Suspend function should be called only from a coroutine
    // or another suspend function:
    val a = a()
    println("Result is $a")
}
launch(Unconfined) {
    (1..10).forEach(action)
}
```

Furthermore, it isn't fixable because:

```
val action: suspend (Int) -> Unit = {
    val a = a()
    println("Result is $a")
}
launch(Unconfined) {
    // suspend (Int) -> Unit cannot be applied to (T) -> Unit
    (1..10).forEach(action)
}
```

What is the story here in terms of the static type system? The current situation looks like a quick hack where an inline block containing a `suspend fun` call is still inferred to a non-suspend type signature.

Is this an area where the design will be improved before being finalized?

Answer (score 5):

The `suspend` and normal functional types are not subtypes of each other and thus cannot be assigned or passed to a function in place of each other:

```
val f: () -> Unit = { }
val g: suspend () -> Unit = f // Type mismatch

val f: suspend () -> Unit = { }
val g: () -> Unit = f // Type mismatch
```

This is why a `suspend (Int) -> Unit` cannot be passed to `forEach`.

Basically, the restriction for suspend functions to be called only in other suspend functions works irrespective to the type system. Such calls should simply be placed inside a suspend function or a suspend lambda or inlined into one. So, this should also work:

```
val action: suspend (Int) -> Unit = {
    val a = a()
    println("Result is $a")
}
launch(Unconfined) {
    (1..10).forEach { action() } // The call is inlined into a suspend lambda
}
```

I've filed an issue about supporting `(1..10).forEach(action)` as well: [KT-22186](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22186)

Comment: You said "This is why a `suspend (Int) -> Unit` cannot be passed to `forEach`", but what is the type of the inline lambda in `(1..10).forEach { action() }`? The IDE says it's `(Int) -> Unit`, is there a special rule about calling suspend funs from "inline lambda blocks"? How is this captured in the type system?

Comment: To perhaps stress more clearly my worry, `(1..10).toList().stream().forEach { a() }` doesn't work even though it is also a literal block and has (almost) the same type signature. I know all this hangs on the `inline fun` modifier, but the current rules seem quite hand-wavy and aren't clearly formalized.

Comment: You're right about a special rule for calling suspend functions from inline lambdas: just as I said, a suspend function can be called from inside an inlined function literal inside another suspend function/lambda, and in this case it does not matter whether the literal itself is typed as `suspend` function or not.

Comment: This rule, indeed, works with different notion than the type of the function literal, but IMO it's quite reasonable: you can call a suspend function inside another suspend function/lambda, and allowing such calls only in inlined function literals ensures that the call happens during the outer function execution (which, in turn, is necessary for the compiler to properly transform the suspend function body into a state machine), so that the code calling a suspend function does not leak somewhere outside the outer suspend function.

Comment: Yes, the behavior is reasonable and I'm familiar with all the reasoning behind it. My worry, and my question, is about the formalization of these rules _inside_ the type system, which currently doesn't exist. It's especially confusing that  `suspend` is expressed in the type, but `inline` isn't, so you need extra rules that explain what's allowed and what isn't. What I posted is but one example of design holes you get when you rely on hand-wavy rules that the IDE doesn't clearly present to you.

Comment: As another example that, by analogy, one might expect to behave differently than it actually does, is this: `inline fun x() { a() }` This doesn't compile because i call `suspend fun a()`, even though it's `inline` and i'm otherwise allowed to write an `inline` lambda with a `suspend` call without it becoming an `inline suspend` lambda. Again, I'm familiar with the reasoning on why this must be, but this is yet another thing to write special-cased rules about.